# Texmaker (read only) - how to change this option

Tags: texmaker

I am new to Texmaker. I am using version 5.1.4 on Windows 10.

After the number 1 2 3 in the banner above the two screens are the words "(read only)".

Advice about how to change this is appreciated,

Bob

Comment: Under the 'General' tab, at the bottom, there is an attribute setting. If 'Read-only' is checked, uncheck it and apply the changes.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks. Firstly, John there does not seem to be  a General tab at the bottom, only: Structure, Messages/Log, Pdf View and Source View. Ready looks greyed out.  The specific problem is that somehow I am in a Read only mode and can't access features that I've seen in videos.

Comment: @bgreen, I suggest to Edit your question and add a screenshot there. Then it may be easier to understand. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me that you are in the [source viewer](https://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/doc.html#SECTION40):

[image]

If so, you are working in the wrong window. Just uncheck the Source view and work in the left window.

[image]

Comment: Many thanks. Pascal Brachet confirmed that the issue was having source viewer activated was the issue.